# Merge neighbouring HTML table cells with same value using JS

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, merge

I've been wrestling with this for a while. I have a table which is automatically generated based on some JSON data, which may vary. I'd like to merge neighbouring cells in the first column which have the same value, e.g. "fish" and "bird" in this table:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>fish</td>
    <td>salmon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fish</td>
    <td>cod</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fish</td>
    <td>plaice</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bird</td>
    <td>robin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bird</td>
    <td>crow</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I don't want to use any libraries ideally, just pure JS.

This is what I would like it to look like:

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">fish</td>
    <td>salmon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cod</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>plaice</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">bird</td>
    <td>robin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>crow</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've been finding different ways to identify the different values and their frequency and then change the rowspan to the right number and subsequently deleting the the other cells but these all broke down in differing use cases.

This is what I have so far:

```js
let table = document.querySelector('table');
let rowCount = 1;

for (let i = 0; i < (table.rows.length - 1); i++) {
  if (table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML === table.rows[i + 1].cells[0].innerHTML) {
    rowCount++;
  } else if (rowCount !== 1) {
    table.rows[i].cells[0].setAttribute('rowspan', rowCount);
    for (let j = (i - rowCount + 1); j < rowCount; j++) {
      table.rows[j].cells[0].remove();
    };
    rowCount = 1;
  };
};
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>fish</td>
    <td>salmon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fish</td>
    <td>cod</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fish</td>
    <td>plaice</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bird</td>
    <td>robin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bird</td>
    <td>crow</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This isn't doing what I want at all but I feel I'm really close! It's trying to count the number of (first column) cells for which the one below has the same value, assigning this number to the rowspan of the last relevant cell and then deleting the subsequent cells before looping back to catch the rest of them. I'd love for my final code to be a variation of this, so can someone show me where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: please share sample scenarios with expected table rows

Comment: @NagaSaiA Thanks - good point, added to the question now (https://jsfiddle.net/5rdw6v4h/)

Comment: Possible side-note: you possibly want those to be `<th>`s at that point (at least with the context in the simple example - I could be wrong.).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You were indeed pretty close!

A way to simplify quite a bit is to keep a reference to the current "header" cell, i.e. the one you want to increase the `rowspan` of. That way you don't have to deal with indexes at all, yielding a very straightforward algorithm:

- For each row

  - Set *firstCell* to the row's first cell
  - If this is the first row OR *firstCell*'s text is different from *headerCell*'s text

    - Set *headerCell* to *firstCell*
  - Otherwise

    - Increase *headerCell*'s *rowSpan* by 1
    - Remove *firstCell*

In JavaScript, it looks like this:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');

let headerCell = null;

for (let row of table.rows) {
  const firstCell = row.cells[0];
  
  if (headerCell === null || firstCell.innerText !== headerCell.innerText) {
    headerCell = firstCell;
  } else {
    headerCell.rowSpan++;
    firstCell.remove();
  }
}
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>fish</td>
    <td>salmon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fish</td>
    <td>cod</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>fish</td>
    <td>plaice</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bird</td>
    <td>robin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bird</td>
    <td>crow</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this is a really elegant solution. I'm now having an issue applying this to all of a table's columns. For some reason I get a type error: 'TypeError: firstCell is undefined'. All I'm doing is changing firstCell = row.cells[0] to firstCell = row.cells[i] and wrapping the code in a for loop for each of the table's columns. Do you know what's going on?

Comment: I've also found that simply repeating the function twice (as a test) with a different index in row.cells[x] also doesn't work. There's no error, but only the first function seems to have any effect. I'm really very confused!

Comment: @Ant did you manage to figure out how to dynamically do the same thing for all the table columns?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with the same issue. I have found a solution that works with all the columns.

The idea mainly revolves around @Jordan's listed solution.

So, if you want to merge neighboring cell of same values for all columns, try out this solution.

```html
// we define a function that performs the mergin part 

function mergeCells(table, startIndex) {
  let headerCell = null;

  for (let row of table.rows) {
    const firstCell = row.cells[startIndex];

    if (headerCell === null || firstCell.innerText !== headerCell.innerText) {
      headerCell = firstCell;
    } else {
      headerCell.rowSpan++;
      firstCell.remove();
    }
  }
}

// to run it 
// mergeCells(table, 0) => merged the same cell values of 1st column
// mergeCells(table,1) => merges the same cell values of 2nd col, and so on...

// now we can loop thru our columns and run the function in *REVERSE ORDER* beacuse in direct order, once the columns get changed the function doesnt work as its supposed to.

// for simplicity lets assume an arbitarty array of columns. 

let cols = [1,2,3] // considering you have 3 columns

 for (
    let i = cols.length - 1;
    i >= 0;
    i--
  ) {
    mergeCells(table, i);
  }

// you can modify this code based on your needs
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Can you provide a full working example as @Jordan's?