# Merge Table rows with same values using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So i am trying to create an html table using a vanilla js function. This function recieves an INPUT [ a data set] and a config[ (Config is to select field, transform(this can be a key or function) and defines whether common values should be merged)]

so far, I have reached this much. where in my function is creating an html table like so:
[image]

but what i want to achieve is something like this:
[image]

as you can probably see, the expected outcome is clubbing duplicate information [ this is coming from the config]

additionally please find the code sandbox[sample INput and config there] here: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-dawn-jc3qf3?file=/src/index.js

any suggestions/leads on how to achieve the expected outcome is very appreciated.

My Progress, So far:

- script.js

```html
import "./styles.css";
import { INPUT, config } from "../data";
import groupBy from "../utils";

function genReport(data, config = []) {
  const tableContainer = document.getElementById("table-container");

  // Create table element
  const table = document.createElement("table");

  // Create table header row
  const headerRow = table.insertRow();

  // Loop through table data to create table headers
  for (let { HeaderName } of config) {
    // console.log("KEY IN CONFIG", key);
    const th = document.createElement("th");
    th.textContent = HeaderName;
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  }

  // Create table body
  const tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  let previousValues = null;
  let currentValues = {};

  // Loop through table data to create table rows
  for (let i = 0; i < INPUT.length; i++) {
    const row = tbody.insertRow();

    // Loop through each key in the row data to create table cells
    for (let j = 0; j < config.length; j++) {
      let field = config[j]["Column"];
      let value = INPUT[i][field];

      // insert value
      const cell = row.insertCell();

      cell.textContent = value || field(INPUT[i]);

      // if merged is true and column  string
    }
    console.log(previousValues);
    console.log("END OF LOOP", i);
  }

  // Add table body to table element
  table.appendChild(tbody);

  // Add table element to the table container
  tableContainer.appendChild(table);
}

genReport(INPUT, config);
```

- INUT Data and config data

```html
import moment from "moment";

const INPUT = [
  {
    Organization: "Google",
    UserId: "akumar",
    UserName: "Ashok Kumar",
    Department: "Sales",
    Designation: "Sales",
    CheckInTime: 1548909000000,
    CheckOutTime: 1548945000000
  },
  {
    Organization: "Google",
    UserId: "akumar",
    UserName: "Ashok Kumar",
    Department: "Sales",
    Designation: "Sales",
    CheckInTime: 1549081800000,
    CheckOutTime: 1549110600000
  },
  {
    Organization: "FB",
    UserId: "phanis",
    UserName: "Phani Sai",
    Department: "Sales",
    Designation: "Sales",
    CheckInTime: 1548909000000,
    CheckOutTime: 1548945000000
  },
  {
    Organization: "FB",
    UserId: "phanis",
    UserName: "Phani Sai",
    Department: "Sales",
    Designation: "Sales",
    CheckInTime: 1549081800000,
    CheckOutTime: 1549110600000
  },
  {
    Organization: "FB",
    UserId: "lakshmig",
    UserName: "Laskhmi Gayathri",
    Department: "Quality",
    Designation: "QA Engineer",
    CheckInTime: 1549081800000,
    CheckOutTime: 1549110600000
  },
  {
    Organization: "FB",
    UserId: "lakshmig",
    UserName: "Laskhmi Gayathri",
    Department: "Quality",
    Designation: "QA Engineer",
    CheckInTime: 1549081800000,
    CheckOutTime: 1549110600000
  }
];

const config = [
  { HeaderName: "Organization", Column: "Organization", Merge: true },
  {
    HeaderName: "Department",
    Column: "Department",
    Merge: true
  },
  {
    HeaderName: "UserName",
    Column: "UserName",
    Merge: true
  },
  {
    HeaderName: "Date",
    Column: ({ CheckInTime }) => {
      return moment(CheckInTime).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    },
    Merge: false
  },
  {
    HeaderName: "Time",
    Column: ({ CheckInTime, CheckOutTime }) => {
      // Column can be a string or callback which can be called with the specific row record to get the computed column value.
      const secs = (CheckOutTime - CheckInTime) / 1000;
      // TODO: Return in (x Hrs y Mins) format.
      return secs / 60 + " Mins"; // Returning in minutes
    },
    Merge: false
  }
];

module.exports = { INPUT, config };
```

Comment: provide your debugging details in form of a [repro] on this site directly and I will help you.

Comment: Your question will received a better response if you first show an attempt to solve the problem yourself.  You might start by trying to transform your data into the tree structure used in the table.  [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) would be one way to group the data by Org, Dept, and User.

Comment: I have tried solving the problem, its in the code sandbox. I am a little confused about the merging part. Did you miss the code sandbox link?

Comment: @Yogi i also have a function that groups the data with the key.But i am unable to use it with the context of merging cells with common values

Comment: @tacoshy added the script file and the data too. see if we figure out the merging cells based on the config, part?

Comment: I found a similar solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56587070/merge-neighbouring-html-table-cells-with-same-value-using-js


works fine, except the fac that i want to dynamically do the same thing for all columns. 

notice the rowscells[0] in the above link's soln snippet - that refers to the first column, i want to do that for all columns in my table. @tacoshy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just when I was about to go crazy, I found a way to do it.

Its brute force at the least

The extended solution is here : https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-table-jc3qf3?file=/src/index.js